# Incrementing an upvote with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular and am trying to build to learn. I have the following array in a controller.  This represents a trade of two players (from two teams).
I think my logic is spot on, why isn't my code working?

```
$scope.unique = [["Name", "Name", "Name", "Name", {"upvotes": 0}]]
//more can be added to the outer array, in sets of five like this.
```

In the same controller I have the following function:

```
$scope.incrementUpvotes = function(value) {
       value[4].upvotes++;
       };
```

In my Angular view I am trying to have an ng-repeat, with ng-click incrementing the upvote when this area is clicked. The upvote is working, but it's only being rendered for the first five elements, the ng-repeat doesn't seem to be working.

```
<div class="text-center" ng-repeat="value in unique">
                  <span ng-click="incrementUpvotes(value)">
                    {{value[0]}} and {{value[1]}} for {{value[2]}} and {{value[3]}} upvotes: {{value[4].upvotes}}
                  </span>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you logic is spot on, the error is coming from the fact that your array is multi-dimensional. To fix it as is look at Anik's answer.

But let me suggest a better structure that will make your code much more readable, maintainable and more aligned to JavaScript conventions

```
$scope.teams = [
  {
      members: ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4"],
      upvotes: 0
  },
  {
      members: ["Name5", "Name6", "Name7", "Name8"],
      upvotes: 0
  }
];
```

So now your upvote function is more readable like so:

```
$scope.incrementUpvotes = function(team) {
   team.upvotes++; 
};
```

And so is your HTML much cleaner now:

```
<div class="text-center" ng-repeat="team in teams">
   <span ng-click="incrementUpvotes(team)">
   {{team.member[0]}} and {{team.member[1]}} for {{team.member[2]}} and {{team.member[3]}} upvotes: {{team.upvotes}}
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks alot I am almost there, but I can't seem to push everything to $scope.teams properly. What am I doing wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/youngfreezy/nwe5ygtm/ Now the incrementer is working, but the ng-repeat part (showing the rest of the values) isn't.

Comment: can you simplify that fiddle into a actually working example? so I can figure out what you want to do. You can just assume data you get back from your service and hard-code it.

Comment: Sure will do tomorrow am exhausted from all the coding today!

Answer (score 0):

I think your structure is a bit confusing. Try something like this:

JS

```
  $scope.unique = [{team: ["Name", "Name", "Name", "Name"], "upvotes": 0},
                   {team: ["Name", "Name", "Name", "Name"], "upvotes": 0}]

  $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(value) {
       value.upvotes++;
    };
```

HTML

```
 <div class="text-center" ng-repeat="value in unique">
   <div ng-click="incrementUpvotes(value)">
     <span ng-repeat="v in value.team track by $index">
       {{v}}
     </span>
     <span>
     upvotes: {{value.upvotes}}
     </span>
   </div>
  </div>
```

See it working here (click on the row to increment vote): http://www.bootply.com/7LOE1zpE4z

Comment: I think we provided the adequate answer already. it is up to you to apply it. We cannot write the code for you.